# Cylinder cross-sections become inconsistent when using curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I drew a bezier curve and tried to applied curve modifier to a long cylinder with this bezier curve. I noticed that the generated cylinder has self-penetration on its cross sections. How to avoid this? And how to align the cylinder with the curve? The curve has an origin outside the curve. I don't think it is hard to edit the origin point of the curve. Any hints are appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the curve and the cylinder should have their origin at the exact same position, is it the case?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have reversed handles on control points.

Select the Bezier Curve and enable Curve Edit Mode normals in the Overlays drop down:

[image: Overlays drop down]

set the length to something large and edit the curve.

If the curve handles aren't backwards, it will look like this more or less

[image: curve handles OK]

But if they're backwards, then it will look like this

[image: curve handles reversed]

If they are reversed, then your cylinder will have kinks in the same places

[image: kinks]

To fix the curve, select the control point that has the reversed normals and *rotate* the handle until they point the right way.

You'll have to do this for every screwed up control handle.  It looks like you have two.

Comment: I have opened up the bezier curve (see above). It may contain reversed normals. I generated the bezier curve by linking points. Is it a better way to control the normals instead of rotating the handle(which should be the points, right)?

Comment: Typical to extrude new control points from one end or the other